# logging MySQL response from PHP page

Tags: php, mysql

When I insert a record, I get the message "1 row affected" and while updating "Rows matched:1 Changed:1"
How do I get these messages from PHP code?

```
mysql> insert into mytest values ('103');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.26 sec)

mysql> update mytest set id = 12 where id = 10;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: I don't think you can get the exact verbose string, but you should be able to get the numeric number of row(s) affected when you perform any update, delete, insert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `mysql_affected_rows()` method:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query('insert into mytest values ('103');');
printf("Records inserted: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());

mysql_query('update mytest set id = 12 where id = 10;');
printf("Records updated: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
```

Comment: I had to add the value in double quotes like... "103"

Answer (score 1):

Those strings only exist in the context of the `mysql` CLI tool; they aren't actually sent by the server. See [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) and [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`mysql_affected_rows`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) and [`mysqli_affected_rows`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)